# Symfony2: Functional testing in Request Scope using a Service depending on a Request Listener Service

Tags: symfony, scope, request, phpunit, listener

I'm new with services and phpUnit.

So I'm trying to test my (working) services. Here is my `services.yml`:

```
services:
    history_cookie:
        class:        VENDOR\Bundle\Service\Visitor\EventListener\HistoryCookie
        scope:        request
        tags:
            -
                name: kernel.event_listener
                method: onKernelRequest
                event: kernel.request
    map_utm_origin:
        class:        VENDOR\Bundle\Service\Visitor\MapUtmOrigin
        arguments:    [@history_cookie, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        scope:        request
```

To summarize the rest of my code, I've got a ***listener*** service called `HistoryCookie` which retrieve some GET parameters (utm) if present, and store them in Session and private variables.

And my other Service, `MapUtmOrigin`, retrieves the HistoryCookie Service object to get those parameters, and map them to an object from the database.

**1. Because I'm also pretty new with Services, is it the best way to deal with that situation ?**

**2. In Unit Testing, I can't make it work**

Here is my last try of functional testing (*I'm using TheodoEvolutionSessionBundle to manage Symfony 1.2 / 1.4 Sessions*) :

```
    $configuration = $this->getMock('Theodo\Evolution\Bundle\SessionBundle\Manager\BagManagerConfigurationInterface');
    $configuration->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getNamespaces')
        ->will($this->returnValue(array('array', 'scalar')))
    ;
    $session = new Session(new MockArraySessionStorage());
    $manager = new BagManager($configuration);
    $manager->initialize($session);
    $client = static::createClient();
    $container = $client->getContainer();
    $container->enterScope('request');
    $container->set('session', $session);
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/contact?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=nocampaign');
    $container = $client->getContainer();
    ld($container->get("map_utm_origin"));
    ld($session->getBag("symfony/user/sfUser/attributes"));
```

But `$container->get("map_utm_origin")` is always empty (not null), like it has never handled the request (it is normally initialized in `onKernelRequest($requestEvent)`), though `$session->getBag("symfony/user/sfUser/attributes")` has correctly been set!